# How can I get gdk-x11-3.0 on OS X?

Tags: macos, homebrew, x11

Building an [application](https://github.com/pdfpc/pdfpc) from source (yikes), I get this on `cmake`:

```
-- checking for module 'gdk-x11-3.0'
--   package 'gdk-x11-3.0' not found
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.3.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:340 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.3.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:502 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:12 (pkg_check_modules)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I *have* already `homebrew install gtk+3` and a bunch of other things that came to mind (and were listed as dependencies), so I have no idea what this is and where I can get it, or if it is, indeed, missing.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

**Config and Steps Taken**

- `brew doctor` is clean: `Your system is ready to brew.`
- homebrew is `upgrade`d and `update`d
- I am running OS X 10.10.5

Brew's got:

```
atk 2.16.0
atkmm 2.22.7
autoconf 2.69
automake 1.14.1 1.15
bison 3.0.4
boost 1.58.0
brew-cask 0.53.3 0.54.0 0.54.1 0.56.0
cabextract 1.5 1.6
cairo 1.14.2 1.14.2_1
cairomm 1.11.2_1
cloog 0.18.1 0.18.3
cloog-ppl015 0.15.11
cmake 3.3.1
ctags 5.8 5.8_1
ffmpeg 2.6.3 2.7.1 2.7.2 2.7.2_1
fontconfig 2.11.1
freetype 2.5.5 2.6 2.6_1
gcc 4.9.2_1 5.1.0 5.2.0
gcc46 4.6.4
gd 2.1.1
gdbm 1.11
gdk-pixbuf 2.30.8
gettext 0.19.4 0.19.5.1
ghostscript 9.15 9.16
git 2.2.1 2.3.6 2.4.0 2.4.1 2.4.2 2.4.3 2.4.4 2.4.5 2.4.6 2.5.0 2.5.1 2.5.2
glib 2.44.0 2.44.1
glib-networking 2.44.0
glibmm 2.44.0
gmp 6.0.0a
gmp4 4.3.2
gnutls 3.3.17.1
gobject-introspection 1.44.0
gsettings-desktop-schemas 3.16.1
gst-plugins-bad 1.4.5
gst-plugins-base 1.4.5
gst-plugins-good 1.4.5
gst-plugins-ugly 1.4.5_1
gstreamer 1.4.5
gtk+ 2.24.28_2
gtk+3 3.16.6
gtk-mac-integration 2.0.8
gtkmm 2.24.4_1
gtkmm3 3.16.0
harfbuzz 1.0.3
hicolor-icon-theme 0.15
icu4c 55.1
isl 0.12.2 0.14.1
jasper 1.900.1
jbig2dec 0.12
jpeg 8d
lame 3.99.5
libepoxy 1.3.1
libffi 3.0.13
libgee 0.16.0
libgpg-error 1.13 1.17 1.19 1.20 1.20_1
libgphoto2 2.5.7 2.5.8
libicns 0.8.1_1
libksba 1.3.0 1.3.3
libmpc 1.0.3
libmpc08 0.8.1
libpng 1.6.17 1.6.18
libsigc++ 2.4.1
libsoup 2.50.0
libtasn1 4.5
libtiff 4.0.3 4.0.4
libtool 2.4.2 2.4.6
libusb 1.0.19
libusb-compat 0.1.5
libvo-aacenc 0.1.3
libyaml 0.1.6 0.1.6_1
little-cms2 2.7
makedepend 1.0.5
mpfr 3.1.2-p11 3.1.3
mpfr2 2.4.2
nettle 2.7.1
node 0.12.7 0.12.7_1
openjpeg 1.5.2_1
openssl 1.0.1g 1.0.1j_1 1.0.2a-1 1.0.2c 1.0.2d 1.0.2d_1
p7zip 9.20.1
pandoc 1.13.2 1.13.2.1 1.14 1.14.0.2 1.14.0.4 1.15.0.4 1.15.0.5 1.15.0.6
pandoc-citeproc 0.6 0.7.0.1_1 0.7.1.1 0.7.2 0.7.3
pango 1.36.8_2
pangomm 2.36.0
pcre 8.36 8.37
pixman 0.32.6
pkg-config 0.28
poppler 0.35.0
ppl011 0.11 0.11_1
py2cairo 1.10.0_1
pygobject 2.28.6
pygtk 2.24.0_1
python 2.7.10_2
qt 4.8.7
readline 6.3.6 6.3.8
ruby 2.2.0 2.2.2 2.2.3
sane-backends 1.0.24_1
sqlite 3.8.11.1
tcl-tk 8.6.4
tree 1.7.0
unrar 5.2.6 5.2.7
vala 0.28.1
wine 1.6.2
winetricks 20150316 20150416 20150706 20150810
x264 r2533 r2555
xvid 1.3.3 1.3.4
xz 5.2.1
```

Comment: Which OSX version are you using? Did you run `brew doctor` etc?

Comment: yes of course, sorry – updated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer**

I think the problem here is that a lot of homebrew packages don't include X11 support by default if there is a more relevant (i.e. OS X specific) backend available. But PDFPC is looking for the X11 backend for GDK.

**Long answer**

GDK is distributed as part of GTK+ and if you look at the [formula for GTK+3](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/gtk+3.rb) it explicitly disables the X11 backend.

```
args = %W[
  --disable-debug
  --disable-dependency-tracking
  --prefix=#{prefix}
  --disable-glibtest
  --enable-introspection=yes
  --disable-schemas-compile
  --enable-quartz-backend
  --disable-x11-backend
]
```

You could edit the formula to include the x11 backend and then run `brew install --build-from-source --verbose gtk+3`, but then the build fails before it even gets to the compile stage.

```
configure: error: Package requirements (atk atk-bridge-2.0) were not met:

No package 'atk-bridge-2.0' found
```

So you can then add `depends_on "at-spi2-atk" to the GTK+3 formula to get homebrew to install that package, and now GTK+3 gets through the configure stage and starts build. Unfortunately it then fails with errors because by default Cairo isn't installed with the X11 backend.

```
In file included from gdkapplaunchcontext-x11.c:27:
../../gdk/x11/gdkprivate-x11.h:46:10: fatal errorIn file included from gdkdevice-core-x11.c:In file included from 26gdkasync.c::
47:
../../gdk/x11/gdkprivate-x11.h:../../gdk/x11/gdkprivate-x11.h46::4610::10 :fatal error : fatal error'cairo-xlib.h' file not found
In file included from gdkcursor-x11.c:33:
../../gdk/x11/gdkprivate-x11.h:46:10: fatal error: 'cairo-xlib.h' file not found
#include <cairo-xlib.h>
         ^
#include <cairo-xlib.h>
         ^
: 'cairo-xlib.h' file not found
#include <cairo-xlib.h>
         ^
: 'cairo-xlib.h' file not found
#include <cairo-xlib.h>
         ^
1 error1 error generated.
1 error generated.
```

So then you can remove cairo and reinstall it with the X11 backend option.

```
brew remove cairo
brew install --with-x11 cairo
```

But now it fails with problems in libepoxy.

```
In file included from gdkdisplay-x11.c:40:
./gdkglcontext-x11.h:28:10: fatal error: 'epoxy/glx.h' file not found
#include <epoxy/glx.h>
         ^
  CC       gdkglcontext-x11.lo
1 error generated.
make[3]: *** [gdkdisplay-x11.lo] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from gdkglcontext-x11.c:23:
./gdkglcontext-x11.h:28:10: fatal error: 'epoxy/glx.h' file not found
#include <epoxy/glx.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make[3]: *** [gdkglcontext-x11.lo] Error 1
make[2]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [install] Error 2
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

This is because [the author of libepoxy dropped support for GLX on OS X](https://github.com/anholt/libepoxy/releases/tag/v1.3) back a few months ago.

> Another big change is that OSX drops GLX support. I had had
>   near-universal complaints about including it, and its seems like X on
>   OSX is really not used these days (The lack of activity on its X
>   server makes that pretty obvious).

And this is where I throw in the towel. :)

Comment: Are you still can't install GDK for OS X?

Comment: @don-prog This question wasn't about installing GDK it was about GDK-X11. GDK is installed as part of GTK+3. It has always installed fine through Homebrew.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [README](https://github.com/pdfpc/pdfpc), `cmake` without movie support should do the trick.

`cmake -DMOVIES=OFF`

Works for me on macOS 10.12 (Sierra).

See also [this issue](https://github.com/pdfpc/pdfpc/issues/74).

Comment: I've compiled pdfpc on macOS 10.12.6. I can view https://pdfpc.github.io/demo/pdfpc-demo.pdf and try out different features of pdfpc. However, the viewer is not in fullscreen and there seems to be no option for this. Is your pdfpc program in fullscreen?

Comment: @Hotschke I can not help here since I have no access to a Mac anymore. I will probably set up a VM in the next days but I'll first have to see if everything works properly.